# Debido a las recientes mejoras de seguridad en Cloud Storage para Firebase, debes actualizar la configuración de tu proyecto

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

Estoy bloqueado con este mensaje que me aparece en el apartado Storage de Firebase.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Al intentar solucionar el problema indica lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Les agradezco cualquier ayuda

He intentado agregar todos los permisos que se me ocurren a la cuenta de servicio asociada pero sin exito.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Tambien he creado una nueva cuenta de servicio.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow, te invito a hacer el [tour]. Diría que debes asignar el rol: 
roles/firebase.admin

Answer (score 0):

Tuve el mismo problema al intentar usar el Storage. Sin embargo, encontré una solución que puede ayudarte a resolver este inconveniente. A continuación, te proporciono los pasos que seguí:

- Accede a la consola de Google Cloud y localiza el bucket que deseas eliminar (en este caso el que te da problemas).
- Elimina el bucket desde la consola de Google Cloud. Asegúrate de tener los permisos adecuados para realizar esta acción.
- Accede a Firebase Console.
- En Firebase Console, selecciona el proyecto correspondiente.
- Navega hasta la sección de Storage.
- Haz clic en el botón "Comenzar" o "Crear un bucket" para configurar un nuevo bucket de almacenamiento.
- Sigue los pasos proporcionados por Firebase Console para configurar el nuevo bucket. Asegúrate de seleccionar las opciones adecuadas, como el nombre del bucket y las opciones de almacenamiento.
- Finaliza la configuración del nuevo bucket según tus necesidades.
  Una vez creado el nuevo bucket, podrás utilizarlo en tu aplicación.

Al eliminar el bucket desde la consola de Google Cloud y crear uno nuevo desde Firebase Console, te aparecerá como si estuvieras configurando el almacenamiento desde cero. Asegúrate de revisar y ajustar cualquier configuración adicional que necesites.

Espero que estos pasos te sean útiles y te permitan resolver el problema. ¡Buena suerte!

Comment: Eliminar el bucket y volver a crearlo estas seguro que funcionaría? Revisar [answer],

Comment: Si, eso me funcionó a mi, en el caso de él, sería eliminar el bucket comingout-dev... Cuando lo borres, en firebase te saldra como cuando lo creas por primera vez y ahí debería dejarte utilizarlo, al principio intente con los permisos que utilizó él y tampoco funcionaba, así que los quité, hice eso y me funcionó.